# Postgres - How to surround parameter value with single quote

Tags: postgresql

I want to delete data from the Postgres table which are older than n days.
For which I am using the below-stored procedure, I want to pass n days via parameter, but it's failing at runtime.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE usp_deletelog(DaystoDelete integer)
language plpgsql    
as $$
DECLARE
  maxcurrenttime timestamp;
BEGIN
  maxcurrenttime := (SELECT MAX(log_time_to_timestamp) FROM public.interface_execution_log_VJ);
  RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', maxcurrenttime;

  DELETE FROM public.interface_execution_log_VJ
  WHERE log_time_to_timestamp <= ( maxcurrenttime - '1 days'::interval);  -- works if hardcoded i.e. 1, how to pass the parameter instead i.e. DaystoDelete with single quotes ?

  COMMIT;
END;$$;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the function `make_interval()` for that:

```
maxcurrenttime - make_interval(days => daystodelete);
```

Alternatively you can multiply a one day interval:

```
maxcurrenttime - interval '1 day' * daystodelete
```